# Is it possible to get access to the `NotificationManagerService`?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've tried `context.getSystemService(...)` for every iteration of the classname I could think of, but no dice.

[Here's the NotificationManagerService code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java) and [here is the place it gets created.](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java#L1174)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get access to the `NotificationManagerService`?

Sure. Fork Android, and modify the system code to use `NotificationManagerService` as you see fit.

If you mean from an ordinary Android app, then you have access to the `NotificationManager` system service, which provides a local API that communicates with the `NotificationManagerService` over IPC.

If you mean from an ordinary Android app, but getting access to things inside of `NotificationManagerService` that are not part of that IPC protocol, then that is not possible.